# How can i compare the user input with some constant 1, 2 like a switch case in assembly (NASM)?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

In the question below, i saw how to do a compare between user input and some option specified by the programmer.
[Calculator in Assembly Language - Linux x86 & NASM - Division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435659/calculator-in-assembly-language-linux-x86-nasm-division?rq=1)
But in my case isn't work.
Here is the peace of my code.

```
section .data
    msgTes db 'NEW ELEMENT'
    msgTes_len equ $-msgTes

section .bss
    opt resb 2
     .
     .
     .
new_element:     ; option one is a new element
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msgTes
    mov edx, msgTes_len
    int 80h

    pop ebp
    ret

read_option:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, 3  ; reading the option
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, opt
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    mov ah, [opt] ; which option the user entered?
    sub ah, '0'
    cmp ah, 1
    je new_element

    pop ebp
    ret
```

There is a menu with the options, but is irrelevant for the question.
Why the message "NEW ELEMENT" isn't printed?

Comment: Doing a `je` to something that ends with a `ret` generally isn't a good idea. Other than that, print out what you've got at `opt` or use a debugger to set a breakpoint at `mov ah,[opt]` so that you know what you're actually comparing against.

Comment: Ok, but how to get back in the next instruction after the je? I was using call, but in this case, i can't make the decision for the program...

Comment: If you want to do a `call` if the zero flag is set, then you can a construct like `jnz skip / call foo / skip:`.

Comment: I don't see a prompt for the menu input. How do you know it executed the `read_option` portion of the code? Where's the entry point?

Comment: lurker, the read_option is executed! Michael was correct! There is a segmentation fault because of the ret instruction in the new_element! I have to set a jmp instruction inside the new_element to return for the normal flow of the program and setting the label for the jmp... This is the solution! Thanks all the attention!